# Graphic novel about a boy and his friend who are accidentally sent to another dimension by an alien and meet a redheaded girl with an eyepatch

Tags: story-identification, isekai, graphic-novel

I've forgotten the title to a graphic novel but it's basically about a boy and his nerd friend who are accidentally sent to another dimension by an alien and meet a redheaded girl with an eyepatch. She can also transform into a pink octopus or kraken to fight off another sea creature for them that was about to attack.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: I read it in 2013 i believe. And im not sure about the cover but ik the artstyle looks similar to invader zim and poptropica

Comment: I think it was published in 2010 or 2012

Comment: Do remember anything about the author's name (or the length of the author's name).